# Neo4j JDBC driver error "setEscapeProcessing is not supported by Neo4jStatement" in SQL Workbench/J

Tags: jdbc, neo4j, cypher, sql-workbench-j

I want to execute multiple semi-colon delimited Cypher statements in SQL Workbench/J the same way I can run multiple selected SQL statements with the Ctrl+E shortcut.

Here is a small example (modified from the movies dataset):

```
CREATE (TheMatrix:Movie {title:'The Matrix', released:1999, tagline:'Welcome to the Real World'});
CREATE (Keanu:Person {name:'Keanu Reeves', born:1964});
CREATE (Carrie:Person {name:'Carrie-Anne Moss', born:1967});
CREATE (Laurence:Person {name:'Laurence Fishburne', born:1961});
CREATE (Hugo:Person {name:'Hugo Weaving', born:1960});
CREATE (AndyW:Person {name:'Andy Wachowski', born:1967});
CREATE (LanaW:Person {name:'Lana Wachowski', born:1965});
CREATE (JoelS:Person {name:'Joel Silver', born:1952});
CREATE
  (Keanu)-[:ACTED_IN {roles:['Neo']}]->(TheMatrix),
  (Carrie)-[:ACTED_IN {roles:['Trinity']}]->(TheMatrix),
  (Laurence)-[:ACTED_IN {roles:['Morpheus']}]->(TheMatrix),
  (Hugo)-[:ACTED_IN {roles:['Agent Smith']}]->(TheMatrix),
  (AndyW)-[:DIRECTED]->(TheMatrix),
  (LanaW)-[:DIRECTED]->(TheMatrix),
  (JoelS)-[:PRODUCED]->(TheMatrix);
```

I get the error **"setEscapeProcessing is not supported by Neo4jStatement."**
How to fix this?

I'm running my local Neo4j instance using [Neo4j JDBC driver version 2.3.2.](https://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases/org/neo4j/neo4j-jdbc/2.3.2/neo4j-jdbc-2.3.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar)

These are my [connection settings](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3DvvWPyWRa6YTdDVzc1cVJIUW8).

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Java 1.8.0_72-b15, SQL Workbench/J Build 119 (2016-01-31)

Comment: Given the JDBC spec and the API doc, not supporting escape processing is technically not allowed, and throwing an SQLException for that is not allowed either (_"SQLException - if a database access error occurs or this method is called on a closed Statement"_). I'm not sure if there is a way to not have SQL Workbench/J call this method.. Consider switching to a different tool, or file a bug with Neo4J that instead of throwing an exception they might want to silently ignore calls to `setEscapeProcessing` and register a warning on the statement instead.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sql-workbench/YztqtDxmiBc/LJ06_88ITBEJ

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks, setting WbSetConfig workbench.db.[dbid].ddl.disable.escapeprocessing=false; works, I'll accept this as answer if you post it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has already been answered in the [SQL Workbench/J forum](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sql-workbench/YztqtDxmiBc/LJ06_88ITBEJ)

> Yes, you can set the property `workbench.db.[dbid].ddl.disable.escapeprocessing` to false, e.g. by using the following SQL statement
>
> `WbSetConfig workbench.db.[dbid].ddl.disable.escapeprocessing=false;`
>
> you need to replace [dbid] with the DBID that is generated for Hive. For details on the DBID please see here:
>
> http://www.sql-workbench.net/manual/settings.html#dbid

Obviously in this case the DBID for Neo4J must be used, not for Hive (as stated in the forum answer because that question was initially for Hive)